# Identifying coordinate systems of racing circuits?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have some "latitude" and "longitude" data that describes the Silverstone motor racing circuit in the UK. The coordinates look something like this:

```
latitude     longitude
+03124.27986 +00061.07652
+03124.27902 +00061.06950 
+03124.27866 +00061.06632 
+03124.27734 +00061.05942 
+03124.27722 +00061.05852 
+03124.27710 +00061.05780
```

These are clearly not "real" degrees & minutes latitudes and longitudes, since the latitudes aren't even valid, and the longitudes are clearly wrong for a place in the UK.

How do I identify the coordinate system used here?

The data is from Circuit Tools, which is a free program http://www.vboxmotorsport.co.uk/index.php/en/products/performance-meters/2-products/39-circuit-tools-driver-analysis-software . Once installed, the data is in C:\ProgramData\Racelogic\CIR Files\

The files are also available independently of the program here: http://www.vboxmotorsport.co.uk/index.php/en/products/performance-meters/performancebox/12-products/video-loggers/35-circuit-tools-track-database#u

Another set of coordinates in the same format, for a Singapore racetrack looks like

```
latitude     longitude
+00077.47468 -06231.29347 
+00077.47699 -06231.29440 
+00077.47890 -06231.29519 
+00077.47957 -06231.29553 
+00077.47959 -06231.29644
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As whuber said, they are lat-long, but in *decimal minutes*. Those are very uncommon, but in a sense, useful, units for geographic coords.

Lat and long at Silverstone:

```
  52.065567 and  -1.020708 (decimal degrees)
3123.93402  and -61.24248  (decimal minutes)
```

1 degree = 60 minutes